# ImageList en WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2017

estoy utilizando WPF y necesito usar varias imágenes para mi apliación. En WinForms se que existe el componente ImageList para poder acceder a ellas de manera más cómoda y quería saber si hay algún componente que cumpla la misma función en WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay un `ImageList` como tal pero puedes usar un `ItemsControl` para lograr el efecto.
Podrías hacer algo así y pasarle una lista con las rutas de las imágenes.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=listaImagenes}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Image Source="{Binding RutaImagen}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```